# How can i solve "unable to open 'read.c': Unable to read file..." in vscode ubuntu

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug my C program in VScode, then this error appears
How can I fix it?

```
Unable to open 'read.c': Unable to read file '/build/glibc-eX1tMB/glibc-2.31/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c' (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file '/build/glibc-eX1tMB/glibc-2.31/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c').
```

launch.json file:

```
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
        "name": "g++ - Build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
        "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
        "sourceFileMap": {
            "/build/glibc-YYA7BZ": "/usr/src/glibc"
        }
        }
    ]
    }
```

tasks.json file:

```
{
    "tasks": [
            {
                    "type": "cppbuild",
                    "label": "C/C++: gcc-9 build active file",
                    "command": "/usr/bin/gcc-9",
                    "args": [
                            "-g",
                            "${file}",
                            "-o",
                            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
                    ],
                    "options": {
                            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
                    },
                    "problemMatcher": [
                            "$gcc"
                    ],
                    "group": {
                            "kind": "build",
                            "isDefault": true
                    },
                    "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
            },
            {
                    "type": "cppbuild",
                    "label": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
                    "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
                    "args": [
                            "-g",
                            "${file}",
                            "-o",
                            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
                    ],
                    "options": {
                            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
                    },
                    "problemMatcher": [
                            "$gcc"
                    ],
                    "group": "build",
                    "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/gcc"
            }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61101972/8742982